# How to add layers before the input layer of model restored from a .pb file?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a .pb model file and I can get the input tensor and output tensor by get_tensor_by_name and then use the input and output tensor to create a saved model which can then be served in tensorflow model server. But currently, the input tensor is images in 3D array format, and I want to add one more layer to decode jpeg encoded strings and feed the result into the current input tensor, Any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add those layers by editing the file export_inference_graph here *https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/export_inference_graph.py#L114-L116.*

You can add any preprocessing tensor evaluation you want here before exporting the inference graph after the placeholder code.